# Is an anonymous function (lambda) in C# on the same thread as the class it's in

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a class and in the constructor I map an event (Xamarin MessagingCenter) to an anonymous function like so

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Application, SocketInfo>(this, "OnData",
            (sender, dataSent) => { code to execute here});
```

I have a variable in the class ....

```
private bool DiscardData { get; set; }
```

The problem is that inside the anonymous function I do not have access to the variable unless I declare it as static ....

I thought the anonymous function was "contained" inside the declaring class...
Can someone explain this to me ?

Comment: the event might not run on the same thread as the main program...

Comment: It really depends on the implementation of Subscribe. I don't know what that method does, but I can say that just using a lambda does not guarantee it being on a new thread.

Comment: Lambdas don't have anything to do with threads.  They're just anonymous functions.  Is the method that defines the lambda a static method?  The `static` keyword likewise has little to do with threading.  It only means all instances of the class share the same property/field/method.

Comment: You'll need to provide more context.  If the lambda has access to statics, it's likely defined in the same class as the statics.  If it only has access to statics in that class, it could be defined statically--which would explain why it doesn't have access to non-static members.   But, we'll need more context to know for sure.